# Match mixed list elements with scanner

Tags: java, arrays

let's say I have a mixed list (String & integer data types) 100's of lines long. 
i.e.

```
Lines=
    <Thanks For 44 55>
    <Helping Me 43 66>
    etc...
```

I want to use the scanner class to match the two strings (& extract the corresponding numbers as well).
How can I write an `isolate` method to perform this. 
The goal is to feed the two corresponding integer values into a separate `calculate` method.
Here's what I have.

```
private List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();


public void isolate( String s, String l){
        if(String s = this.line.matches(".s*") && String  l=this.line.matches(".l*")){
        lineNew = lines[s][l];
        //// extract the integer values (index 2, index 3) from linesNew here        }
    }
```

Comment: Define "mixed array" please. Isn't it just an array of String which is definitely not "mixed"? And if so, change it. Make it an array of custom type, a type that has a String and two ints, and then your comparisons are easy. Edit: and is it an array at all? Your code shows you're using Lists, not arrays. Yes this may be picky but programming is a picky business.

Comment: does your code compile?String s = this.line.matches(".s*") ?

Comment: Again, you're not using arrays, again, it's not a mixed type, it's a String type pure and simple.

Comment: Updated the specifics above, it's a list with integer & string datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

You've stated in comments:

> Updated the specifics above, it's a list with integer & string datatypes.

And I beg to differ, that no, it's a List of String, period. The String might hold representations of ints and sub strings, but they're all held within a String. The key to a decent solution is to not do this, not use String to represent something which logically could be represented in a much sounder fashion. So,...

- Create a custom class, one with two private String and two private int fields,
- with getters and setters, constructors,...
- Make it implement `Comparable<...>` even if it one or both of the numeric fields represents its "natural" order.
- When you read in your line with the Scanner, parse the line into the constituent field types of this custom class of yours, and create an object with it.
- Then place it into your `List<MyCustomClass>`.
- Do this and creating your methods becomes trivial.
- Consider using a 2nd inner Scanner, one for the line, and that helps you parse the line into two Strings and two ints. Be sure to close this inner Scanner with each iteration of the loop so as not to waste resources.

Comment: Details matter, apologies. 
So the data was read initially from a .txt file with a bufferread method. The elements in the list may not actually be understood by java as integer & strings.

Comment: @Javaing: that's fine, but again you should translate the text into OOP compliant data, pure and simple.